# When button clicked, another line of elements (TextView, Spinner, etc) are added

Tags: android, button

I am currently doing one application on recipes. I want to add recipes on the apps. 
I encounter one problem:

For adding the ingredients, when the *AddButton* (the one with '+') is clicked, another line of *TextView*, *Spinner*, *TextView* and *AddButton* will be added in (while the *AddButton* that was clicked on earlier will disappeared). 
[image]

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Simply use View.GONE in button click event,i.e set visibility of button to GONE

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a listview with a custom adapter and on the button click you can set the visibility to the previous add buttons to View.GONE

Comment: Can you recommend some good and simple tutorials on adding elements into `listview with a custom adapter`? I found some of the listview examples, but none of them is what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

```
addButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
addButton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
// your code to add new line of textView, spinner, etc;
}
}
```

try this